# How to publish the article to specific folder in joomla?

Tags: articles, article-manager

I want to publish the article in specific folder?  Just like a following link,

http://a4academics.com/interview-questions/57-c-plus-plus/419-cpp-interview-questions-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to set up your specific categories in the category manager.
Once you have a category saved, you can then set the article to that category.

You can also, after you have the article added to the category, set up a menu item to category blog. Then, any time you add an article to that category, it will automatically be added to the pages as a blog post.